# p:growl do primefaces está mostrando duas vezes o nome CPF

Tags: primefaces

Meu p:growl do primefaces está mostrando duas vezes o nome CPF quando cpf inválido. Estou usando bean validation.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
      <p:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF"  rendered="#{cadastroClienteBean.CPF}"/>
                    <p:inputMask id="cpf" label="CPF" mask="999.999.999-99"  placeholder="___.___.___-__"
                                 value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.documentoReceitaFedral}" size="14"
                                 rendered="#{cadastroClienteBean.CPF}" required="true" 
                                 requiredMessage="CPF deve ser informado">
                    </p:inputMask>





@CPF
@Column(name = "doc_receita_federal", length = 14)
public String getDocumentoReceitaFedral() {
    return documentoReceitaFedral;
}
```

Comment: Poste o código.

Comment: @Laerte, Desculpe. Postei na pergunta

Comment: Como está escrito seu <p:growl />?

Comment: @MarcosSousa   assim. ' <p:growl autoUpdate="true" />'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem varias formar de resolver.
Uma delas e editar a mensagem do validador CPF
@CPF(message="CPF Invalido")

Comment: já fiz isso e não resolveu. Nos dois campos de validação CPF e CNPJ está com esse erro.

Comment: Tire o CPF da mensagem @CPF(message="Invalido")  - o nome do campo vem por padrão pelo campo label do componente.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado